# how do i get this email script in php to work

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to php and I am trying to use it to collect data from a form I have on my website, then post the content of the forms to my email address, but my send.php script keeps giving me errors.

This is what I have:

```
$company=$_POST['company'];
$contact=$_POST['contact_person'];
$position=$_POST['position'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$finance=$_POST['finance'];
$items=$_POST['items'];
$kind=$_POST['kind'];
$date=$_POST['date'];

$body="company name:". $company . "<br />Contact person:".$contact."<br />position:"
      .$position."<br />phone:".$phone."<br />address:".$address."<br />finance:".$finance."<br />items:"
      .$items."<br />date:".$date;


$to = "contact@sigmastrat.com"; //your email address
$message = $body ."<br/><hr/><br/>".$content;
$from = $_POST['email'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to, $message, $headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

I keep getting errors on lines 19 and 22:

```
$message = $body ."<br/><hr/><br/>".$content;  // L19
mail($to, $message, $headers); // L22
```

What am I doing wrong?

The error msgs are:

> Notice: Undefined variable: content in C:\wamp\www\CPIBootstrap\send_d.php on line 19

And:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\CPIBootstrap\send_d.php on line 22

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Usually, when you get an error, there is a message which tells you what sort of error it is. Knowing what that message says is usually *really* helpful for figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: lookup mail on php.net. You mail command misses the subject.
`mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Comment: For `one` thing, you're missing a parameter in your `mail()` function, such as the `subject`, being the 2nd parameter. Add `$subject="Form subject";` then do this `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Comment: you are also using an undefined variable `$content` unless you have it  created some where else.

Comment: also your server isn't running an smtp server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mail()` call is incorrect. The syntax is:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

As well, you're using `$content` without ever having defined it. So mostlikely that's your two errors - incorrect function call parameters, and undefined variables.

Comment: thanks Marc B...

but am left with the last error
"Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\CPIBootstrap\send_d.php on line 22"

Comment: you need to configure mail server on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters aren't correct. Check the [**mail()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

The correct order is:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers)
```

So, I would try:

```
mail($to, 'My Subject', $message, $headers);
```